# How to create chart for date and time

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I get wrong chart when I create line chart. Could someone please advise what I am doing wrong here. Below are the column in excel

[image]

I get below output. Y axis not showing number above 1 and I dont see any line inside the chart

[image]

Comment: `1` = one day. Hours are a fraction of 1. Also, are those actual times, or text that looks like times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the hours are all in **text** format that caused the problem.

You can use this formula to **convert the text into hours**:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(B2)*24
```

See below example:
[image: Example]